# Angular2 - Platforms have to be created via `createPlatform`

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-routing

I have a test in Angular2 where I am including the ROUTER_PROVIDERS and I get this error message :

"ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Platforms have to be created via `createPlatform`!"

First I was getting a "No provider for Router" error, and after this I included the ROUTER_PROVIDERS inside a beforeEachProvider call. that brought this issue up which I dont know how to figure out what it relates to.

My test looks like this currently :

```
import {TestComponentBuilder, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import {async, it, describe, expect, beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';

import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

describe('Header component', () => {

    // Setup the dependencies for this test
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]);

    @Component({
        selector: 'test-header',
        template: `<et-header [username]="username" [user_image_url]="user_image_url"></et-header>`,
        directives: [HeaderComponent]
    })
    class TestHeader {
        username: string = "Header test";
        user_image_url: string = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150";
    }

    it('should sent font-size to x-large', async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
        return tcb.overrideTemplate(TestHeader, '<et-header [username]="username" [user_image_url]="user_image_url"></et-header>')
            .createAsync(TestHeader).then((fixture: any) => {
                fixture.detectChanges();
                let headerDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('header'));
                //expect(headerDebugElement.nativeElement.classList.contains('header')).toBe(true);
                expect(true).toBe(true);
            });
    })));
});
```

Thank you in advance.
Joao Garin

Comment: I'm having the same issue, if anyone has a solution let us know

Answer (score 2):

**FOR ROUTER RELEASE < RC3**

Finally, found a solution to this problem.

When running Unit Tests you need to use

```
import {ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router/testing';
```

to supply the provider for the Router.

**FOR ROUTER RELEASE 3.0.0-alpha.7 (RC3)**

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

class MockRouter { createUrlTree() {} }
class MockActivatedRoute { }

beforeEachProviders(() => [
    provide(Router, { useClass: MockRouter }),
    provide(ActivatedRoute, { useClass: MockActivatedRoute })
]);
```

this will provide the router for your tests

**NOTE: Angular 2 Router now has its own release cycle separate from the rest of the Angular 2 Packages and hence its version numbering is different**

Comment: Yes for the new router that seems to be the solution. for the older router I could not find a way to get it working. but in the meanwhile have also been able to start using the new router and this works!

Comment: this stopped working with rc3. is there a new solution yet?

Comment: yes, i have it in my code, i'll update this when i get a chance

Comment: And no RC4 is here and again not working... I think this is ridiculous. Not of course this answer which is great but their deprecations in every single release... Almost giving up on Angular 2... Thx @Colum though ;)

Comment: I'll fix this answer up for rc4 once I get on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for RC4 to mock the [routerLink] directive when testing a component.

**This will break in the next release given the changes in the master branch.**

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { addProviders } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SpyLocation } from '@angular/common/testing';

class MockRouter {
  createUrlTree() {}
  navigateByUrl() {}
  navigate() {}
}

class MockActivatedRoute { }

beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([
    {provide : Router useClass: MockRouter },
    {provide : ActivatedRoute,  useClass: MockActivatedRoute },
    {provide:LocationStrategy,  useClass: SpyLocation }
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error because of ...

[routerLink] in my HTML.

The correct fix for latest router on RC4 is ...

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, // must be first
  {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}, // must be second
  {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: Mock},
  {provide: Router, useClass: Mock}
]));
```

A github project with this approach is ...

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-coverage

Note that this allows you to use ...

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route1']">Route 1</a>
```

But will fail for ...

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route1']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Route 1</a>
```